# Add html selector infront from child class in LESS

Tags: less, html5boilerplate

In LESS i want be able to write some code like this:

```
article .foo {
    .baa {
       color: red;
       /* what ever magic selector */ html.lt-ie9 {
           color: green;
       }
    }
}
```

and get this output:

```
article .foo .baa {
       color: red;
}

html.lt-ie9 article .foo .baa {
       color: green;
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Use the parent selector like `html.lt-ie9 & {` :)

Comment: [Parent Selectors](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature-changing-selector-order).

Comment: possible duplicate of [LESS CSS syntax useful for modernizr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812056/less-css-syntax-useful-for-modernizr)